# Put an if in an adapter (ViewHolder)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement

I have an adapter that collects data from a database and I want to put that when:

```
txtFPrecio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.PrecioRVA);
```

is = 0 it is not displayed.

I leave the 3 files that I use

Thank you

```
public class RVAdapterAviso extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterAviso.DatosResevaViewHolder> {

    List<DatosAviso> listaReservas;
    RequestQueue request;
    Context context;
    RequestOptions option;
    long doubleClickLastTime = 0L;


    public RVAdapterAviso(List<DatosAviso> listaReservas, Context context) {
        this.listaReservas = listaReservas;
        this.context=context;
        //Opciones para Glide
        option = new RequestOptions().transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(60)).placeholder(R.drawable.load2).error(R.drawable.load2);
        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    @Override
    public DatosResevaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vistadelrvaviso,parent,false);
        DatosResevaViewHolder holder = new DatosResevaViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DatosResevaViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), fullscreen.class);
        intent.putExtra("image",  listaReservas.get(position));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen2(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen3(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen4(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen5(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen6(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen7(), null));
        holder.imageList.add(new SlideModel("https://solobuses.com.ar/img_publi/"+listaReservas.get(position).getfImagen8(), null));

        holder.txtSlider.setImageList(holder.imageList, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP);

        holder.txtFAno.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfAno());
        holder.txtFCarroceria.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfCarroceria());
        holder.txtFButacas.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfButacas());
        holder.txtFChasis.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfChasis());
        holder.txtKm.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getKm());
        holder.txtFMoneda.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfMoneda());
        holder.txtFPrecio.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfPrecio());
        holder.txtFProvincia.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfProvincia());
        holder.txtFCiudad.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfCiudad());
        holder.txtFDescrip.setText(listaReservas.get(position).getfDescrip());

        holder.txtSlider.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - doubleClickLastTime < 300){
                    doubleClickLastTime = 0;
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    doubleClickLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaReservas.size();
    }



    public static class DatosResevaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtFAno, txtFCarroceria, txtFButacas, txtFChasis, txtKm, txtFMoneda, txtFPrecio, txtFProvincia, txtFCiudad, txtFDescrip;
        ImageSlider txtSlider;

        final List<SlideModel> imageList = new ArrayList<>();


        public DatosResevaViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtSlider = (ImageSlider)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageSlider);
            txtFAno = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.AnoRVA);
            txtFCarroceria = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.CarroceriaRVA);
            txtFButacas = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ButacasRVA);
            txtFChasis = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ChasisRVA);
            txtKm = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.KmRVA);
            txtFMoneda = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.MonedaRVA);
            txtFPrecio = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.PrecioRVA);
            txtFProvincia = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProvinciaRVA);
            txtFCiudad = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.CiudadRVA);
            txtFDescrip = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.DescripRVA);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: check on your activity `listaReservas.setfPrecio()` or you can edit your question and add activity code where the viewmodel data is set. Make sure `setfPrecio()` not 0 / null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming that you want to exclude the whole item (not simply hide the price from the viewHolder), you should use a filtered list as source for the recyclerview in order to exclude the items that should be hidden. As alternative, you could directly do a DB query that excludes the unwanted items (adding `WHERE precio > 0`).